# How can i load an image from a playlist without loading the whole playlist?

Tags: spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0, libspotify

i wanted to know if there is another way i could load the playlist image instead of loading the whole playlist and then fetch the image, i know that on the web platform you have a function that called imageFor and you can insert a playlist URI and get an Image.
how ever on the iOS (cocoalibspotify) you must have the image URI if you want to load it directly and if not i need to load the whole playlist.

will be glad to know if i'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CocoaLibSpotify doesn't support playlist images at all - `SPPlaylist` doesn't have an image property.

Comment: any chance it will appear in the next update since i have to load the whole playlist and then load a track in order to get "playlist image"